# how to not re-create itself after screen orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout

I created two layout folder in the layout-land,layout-port containing same files to pick layout depends on the mode change and i added this in my activity.

```
public void  onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig 

{super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);setContentView(R.layout.main);}
```

and in `manifest and android:configChanges="orientation";`

Comment: Each time it get craeted newly how to avoid recreation in orientation change only layou file should getchange

Comment: Why you want that is it slowing your app? if the activity is not destroyed how its going to change the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<activity android:name = "DomainList"
          android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>
```

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  setContentView(R.layout.main);
InitializeUI();} public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); setContentView(R.layout.adult_teeth); InitializeUI();} <activity android:name=".MainScreen"android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"/>

Comment: layout-land-main.xml,layout-port-main.xml how u declare in these format in resource folder,where xml file should be same

Comment: UI changes are working fine,in potriat suppose if i enable button,when i change to landscape same button  should be enable..

Comment: remove on configuration method and give the same xml name for landscape as well as portrait it will be working.. setcontentview(R.layout.main)..

Comment: actually its working fine ...its taking data but here its not taking main.xml from layout-land when i cahange mode to landscape ,actually in the same name file i created layout-port and layout-land,port xml design is different compare to land layout containing file but file name is same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6030/discussion-between-babi-and-nikhilreddy-gujjula)